# Converting java to scala with Generics

Tags: java, scala, generics, playframework, try-catch

I have the next Java code:

```
public static <T> T buildSAMLObject(final Class<T> clazz) {
    T object = null;
    try {
        XMLObjectBuilderFactory builderFactory = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getBuilderFactory();
        QName defaultElementName = (QName)clazz.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME").get(null);
        object = (T)builderFactory.getBuilder(defaultElementName).buildObject(defaultElementName);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create SAML object");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create SAML object");
    }

    return object;
}
```

I am trying to convert it to Scala and so far I got:

```
def buildSAMLObject(clazz: asInstanceOf[T]): [T] T  {
    var obj = builderFactory.getBuilder(defaultElementName).buildObject(defaultElementName).asInstanceOf[T];
    try {
        val builderFactory = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getBuilderFactory();
        val defaultElementName = clazz.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME").get(null).asInstanceOf[QName];
        obj = builderFactory.getBuilder(defaultElementName).buildObject(defaultElementName).asInstanceOf[T];
    } catch 
         {
            case e: IllegalAccessException => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create SAML object")
            case e: NoSuchFieldException   => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create SAML object")
         }

    obj
}
```

The latter is not compiling and I believe this is because  I do not know how to represent  [T] T.  Any suggestions, please?

Comment: There's no reason to make `object` a mutable variable either in Java or in Scala here. Just do `return` inside of the block in Java and use the fact that last value is returned in Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics in method signature causes the error, it should go like this:

```
def buildSAMLObject[T](clazz: Class[T]): T  = {
```

P.S.: In scala newline sumbol is an equivalent of semicolon, you don't need to write them.

Comment: Another Question: What is the Scala equivalent to    T object = null  ?  If I use var obj = null I could get a data type related error

Comment: There is a `Null` class, although what you mean is `Nothing`. But here better would be to use the property of `try`, that it returns value. Simply write `var object = try {...}`

Comment: You can also write `var object: T = null`, but since you are in **Scala** you may try to avoid mutations, nulls, side effects, etc. And write code that is more idiomatic. instead of just translating **Java** - but, if you can't or simply do not want to, there is always a way.

Comment: You can't write `var object: T = null` because `T` could be e.g. `Int`. It requires a constraint on `T`, either `[T <: AnyRef]` (more standard) or `[T >: Null]`.